# How do you use JavaScript to submit a form without using the email method

Tags: html, email, email-spam

I'm trying to get a form to submit without using an email address (for privacy
reasons and so I don't get a load of spam)

---

Note:

I haven't included my email here for privacy.
Don't try and submit something into the form.
Here is my current code.

```html
<form action="mailto:somebody@something.com" method="POST">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="fstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lstname">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">


</form>
```

Comment: Forms usually trigger http requests, and don't send emails, your server would need to send it.

Comment: A form's action attribute value should be an `URI`, not an email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form triggers a HTTP request, due to this being a form you will need an area to store all the forms reply's. Your best option would be to make a brand new email and try to get the form working first before deciding you don't want to use your own personal email address.

You can make a quick and easy email address here; https://www.gmx.co.uk/ this should take about 30 seconds.

As i have said try to get your form to work before deciding were you want the responses to be stored. You could store them in a DB which is what i would do but i would need more information to go into more detail about your question.

Here you will find the correct syntax;

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After your **action** you can either use a relative or absolute address for your HTTP request in my case this is **/action_page.php** which would be a PHP file.

Or if you wish to make an email specifically for your form you can try a syntax like this although i wouldn't overly **mailto** as it may be out of date;

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <h2>Send e-mail to email@email.com:</h2>

 <form action="mailto:email@email.com" method="post"enctype="text/plain">
 Name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="name"><br>
 E-mail:<br>
 <input type="text" name="mail"><br>
 Comment:<br>
 <input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Send">
 <input type="reset" value="Reset">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Is there any other way? (eg like send to an IP address)

Comment: What would your goal be if you sent the user to an IP what would you want to happen?

Comment: Sending it to my own IP as a text file or something so I can read the input